# .swf vulnerabilities in magento

Tags: security, magento

Security scan (by godday) reported that following files are vulnerable.

- /skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploader.swf

As solutions, it has suggested to recompile the .swf using latest Flash. However since this is already compiled by Magento and we don't have .fla. How to fix this issue?

Any suggestion?

Comment: Godaddy provides a *security scan*? *How* did it state the file is vulnerable. Vulnerable how?

Comment: Here's what I mean http://www.godaddy.com/security/website-security.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solutions here, have to apply patch to .swf file. Patch is provided by Adobe http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/915/cpsid_91544.html